# Can I monitor a property for changes without using a custom set accessor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework Core doesn't like it when I use a custom set accessor on a virtual foreign key navigation property with lazy loading enabled. It throws a runtime exception during startup/configuration. I would like to run some custom code every time one of these properties is set though. Is there any way I can make this happen without EF Core yelling at me? Code examples/clarifications below:

```cs
public class CoilUnit
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("project")]
    public virtual CoilProject Project { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class CoilProject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

The above setup works just fine in EF Core, but it doesn't do what I want it to do.

This is what I want:

```cs
public class CoilUnit
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private CoilProject project;

    [ForeignKey("project")]
    public virtual CoilProject Project
    {
        get { return project; }
        set { project = value; /* Other code here */ }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class CoilProject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

On the code side of things, this does what I want, but EF Core doesn't like it and fails to run when I do this.

Is there any way in this situation to have my cake and eat it too? Any way to get the `/* Other Code */` to run properly while also letting EF Core have its way?

Thanks.

Comment: Is adding a SetProject(CoilProject project) method that does the additional logic an option? That way you can keep the default setter.

Comment: @vvasch Of course it's technically possible, but in a team setting, for maintainability, not really unless I also disable the default setter, which would kill EF Core. The point is to make the "public API" (so to speak) of the class such that it is impossible to set CoilUnit.Project without triggering the additional logic.

Comment: Ok, I was just making sure you didn't overlook the obvious. Sorry, no other suggestions from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with lazy loading and custom property setter, but the conflict between the backing field and shadow FK property names.

When applied to navigation property, `ForeignKey` attribute specifies the FK property name. If no such property exists, EF Core will create [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) with that name.

With auto-property the [backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations) name is generated by the compiler, and is **not** `"project"`, so no problem. But in the second case there is already field named `"project"`, so EF Core decides that this is the FK property specified by the attribute. But of course it isn't, and also is not the expected type (`Guid` or `Guid?`), hence the exception.

If you were using conventional FK property/column names (like `ProjectId`), you won't need that attribute and won't have issue. I'm pretty sure you don't care about shadow property name, but the table column name.

So one way to resolve the issue is to remove the `ForeignKey` attribute and use fluent API to configure the FK column name:

```
private CoilProject project;

public virtual CoilProject Project
{
    get { return project; }
    set { project = value; /* Other code here */ }
}
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CoilUnit>()
    .Property<Guid?>(nameof(CoilUnit.Project) + "Id")
    .HasColumnName("project");
```

Another way is to keep the attribute but rename the navigation property backing field to one of the other [supported patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations#basic-configuration), for instance `"_project"`:

```
private CoilProject _project;

[ForeignKey("project")]
public virtual CoilProject Project
{
    get { return _project; }
    set { _project = value; /* Other code here */ }
}
```

Comment: I didn't check this, but if this does work, I think it is the solution.

Comment: Wow.... this was definitely it. The EF Core exception messages are far too esoteric. It makes no sense that this is the answer but it definitely is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other property to keep your buisness logic, which won't be mapped by EF.

```
public class CoilUnit
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private CoilProject project;

    [ForeignKey("project")]
    public virtual CoilProject Project { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual CoilProject ProjectNotMapped
    {
        get { return project; }
        set { project = value; /* Other code here */ } 
    }
}
```

additionaly properties which do not have either getters or setters also won't be mapped [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx):

```
        public virtual CoilProject ProjectNotMapped
        {
            set { project = value; /* Other code here */ } 
        }
```

Comment: Right. I do use `NotMappedAttribute` all over my model classes. This is a definite compromise though, and it's sort of the thing I asked this question in order to avoid. The setter for `Project` is public, and it still doesn't have the business logic attached, which means it's possible to assign a value to the property from anywhere without making sure it gets executed correctly.

Comment: However, while typing out my last comment, I thought of a possible solution.